# How to close all windows in one swoop?

Tags: macos, productivity

I have a lot of open windows.

how do I close them in one fell swoop?

I'm on mojave 10.14.5 [image]

Answer (score 1):

The "close all Finder windows" keyboard shortcut has been the same since the "classic" Mac OS days:

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>W</kbd>

Or if you prefer: Option Command W

You just have to have **one** of the Finder windows the active window.

Comment: Steve Chambers - the basketball player?! :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I tried option command w, but nothing happens

Comment: @nz_21 make sure the Finder has focus when you press the keyboard shortcut, and as per my last sentence in the Answer above the best way to do that is to click on **one** Finder window. If it is still not working you can open a Question, with the symptoms, what you have tried to remediate the issue and the full version of macOS you are using.